# skip_after_action rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m using rails 4.3 and when I´m using the fonction skip_after_action I got an error:

undefined method `skip_after_action' for #UsersController:0x007f5c7ebb6ea8

I´ve try to found if maybe this function isnt in this version of rails but I´ve found nothing.

Maybe someone can help me!

My controller is this one

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
   if params[:support] == 'mobile'
     skip_after_action :intercom_rails_auto_include
     render layout: 'mobile'
   end
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: `skip_after_action` didn't exist before 4.0.2 but is definitely present in 4.3

You should include the FULL error message and trace, which will show exactly which method is missing.  Also show the line where `skip_after_action` is called and the code for the called method. 

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The controller where you put that method should inherit from Applicationcontroller like this : class MyController < ApplicationController

Comment: Ok I just can't use this function like this.. I can use skip_after_action :only for specified an action. But I would like to use a parameter given to the action show to know if i have to skip It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

it seems skip_after_action must be out of action method.

```
skip_after_action :callback, only: :index
def index;end
```